# Addition of variables

Tags: python

I ran into a problem when adding variables. Their values ​​are glued together, but I need to calculate

```
a = check1()
b = check2()
c = check3()
d = check4()
g = check5()
e = check6()
f = check7()
g = сheck8()
i = сheck9()

online = a + b + c + d + g + e + f + g + i
```

functions are all identical:

```
def check1():
    with valve.source.a2s.ServerQuerier(a) as server:
        info = server.info()
        players = server.players()
        return '{player_count}'.format(**info)
```

I get as a result: 007220000

how to count them?

Comment: Can you please share the code and inputs? The information is insufficient to help you.

Comment: We'll need to see the functions' definitions but it looks like they return strings but you expected them to return integers.

Comment: Why would you have nine identical functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be of great help if you pasted the whole code segment here, including the functions. It seems to me that you are returning the values from those functions as strings.

Comment: If you are receiving whole numbers (under 2B) you could try:
`return int('{player_count}'.format(**info))`
otherwise you could try
`return float('{player_count}'.format(**info))`